# AngularJS - Filter out single object in nested data structure

Tags: angularjs, filter, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Data**

```
var data = {
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "Spectrum Series",
            "seriesid": "SpectrumSeries",
            "book": [
                {
                    "name": "White Curse",
                    "bookid": "WhiteCurse",
                    "image": "book1"                    
                },
                {
                    "name": "Blue Fox",
                    "bookid": "BlueFox",
                    "image": "book2"                   
                }
            ]

    … other series
        }
```

**Controller**

```
dnleoApp.controller('BookCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.mybookid = $routeParams.bookid;
    $scope.myseriesid = $routeParams.seriesid;
    $scope.serieslist = data.records;
    $scope.compareSeriesID = function($series) {
        return $series.seriesid == $scope.myseriesid;
    };
    $scope.compareBookID = function($book) {
        return $book.bookid == $scope.mybookid;
    };

});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="series in serieslist | filter: compareSeriesID">
    <ul ng-repeat="book in series.book | filter: compareBookID">
        <li>{{book.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I use nested ng-repeat with filter to filter out a single book of a series using the seriesid (unique) and bookid (unique) from the url. This approach works well but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Yes, or course: instead of loading all the series and all the books of all the series from the backend, when in fact you just care about one book of one serie, load only that book and that seria from the backend. Even with your strategy, I would not use loops in the view to display the information. Instead, I would do that in the controller, and just store the book and the serie in the scope for the view.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I used a nested forEach to filter it out in controller as you suggested. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used nested forEach in the controller to filter out and assign the book object to a scope variable.

**HTML**

```
<div>{{selectedbook.name}}</div>
```

**Controller**

```
dnleoApp.controller('BookCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.mybookid = $routeParams.bookid;
    $scope.myseriesid = $routeParams.seriesid;
    $scope.serieslist = data.records;
    var keepGoing=true;
   angular.forEach($scope.serieslist, function(series){      
       if(keepGoing) {
            if(series.seriesid == $scope.myseriesid){
                angular.forEach(series.book, function(book){
                    if(book.bookid == $scope.mybookid){                         
                        $scope.selectedbook = book;                            
                        keepGoing = false;
                    }
                });               
            }
        }      
   });  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

if you change your data to

```
 var data = {
"records": {
    "SpectrumSeries": {
        "name": "Spectrum Series",
        "seriesid": "SpectrumSeries",
        "book": {
            "book1": {
                "name": "White Curse",
                "bookid": "WhiteCurse",
                "image": "book1"
            },
            "book2": {
                "name": "Blue Fox",
                "bookid": "BlueFox",
                "image": "book2"
            }
        }
    },
    "Series2": {
        "name": "Spectrum Series",
        "seriesid": "SpectrumSeries",
        "book": {
            "book1": {
                "name": "White Curse",
                "bookid": "WhiteCurse",
                "image": "book1"
            },
            "book2": {
                "name": "Blue Fox",
                "bookid": "BlueFox",
                "image": "book2"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then you can just do serieslist[myseriesid].book[bookid] to get the book.

check this fiddle jsfiddle.net/devjit/wdtk370z/5

Or you can set the selected book in controller like

```
    $scope.selectedBook = data.record[$routeParams.seriesid].book[$routeParams.bookid];
```

and in HTML

```
{{selectedBook.name}}
```

Comment: i tried it, for me it works.. check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/devjit/wdtk370z/5/   .

Comment: Yes, now it work. In your initial suggestion it was just "serieslist[myseriesid][bookid]"